# choose from array list elements that match user input

Tags: java

I'm new to java and I'm trying to create a customer database program. There are some `Customers` with different `firstName` but same `lastName` (and visa-versa). If user inputs `Customer` `lastName` to search for and `lastName` matches multiple `Customer`s, how can I show a list of `Customer`s who matched the user's input and then be prompted to select which `Customer` is to be used?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
private Customer searchCustomer(String search) {
Customer customer = null;
for (Customer cust : mockCustomerDatabase) {
    if (cust.getLastName().toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) > -1) 
    return cust;
    }
}
return customer;
}
```

Customer database:

```
private void createMockData() {
Customer cust = new Customer("Brain", "Holtz", "Brian@Holtz.Com");
mockCustomerDatabase.add(cust);
cust = new Customer("Bruce", "Bagley", "Bruce@Bagley.com");
mockCustomerDatabase.add(cust);
cust = new Customer("Courtney", "Lee", "Courtney@lee.com");
mockCustomerDatabase.add(cust);
cust = new Customer("Jacob", "Graf", "Jacob@graf.com");
mockCustomerDatabase.add(cust);
cust = new Customer("Jacob", "Brown", "Jacob@Brown.com");
mockCustomerDatabase.add(cust);
cust = new Customer("Kevin", "Brown", "Kevin@Brown.com");
mockCustomerDatabase.add(cust);
```

Customer Class:

```
public class Customer {
public String firstName;
public String lastName;
public String email;
public Customer(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
this.firstName = firstName;
this.lastName = lastName;
this.email = email;
}

public Customer() {
}

//Getter's and Setter's 
@Override
public String toString() {
return "Customer [firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName       + ",email=" + email + "]";
}

}
```

Comment: You need to start by making the searchCustomer method return a List of Customer objects. You are already looping through the main list of customers so you have most of the logic done.

Comment: @Austin: I figured things out. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lambda Expressions:

```
public Customer  findPersonByName(final String name) {
    return mockCustomerDatabase.stream().filter(p -> p.getName().equals(name)).findAny();
}
```